# 403 ERR_ACCESS_DENIED from bitbucket webhook to jenkins

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins, amazon-ec2, bitbucket

I set up a jenkins server in AWS EKS. It runs in a private subnet on an EC2 & is fronted by an internal ALB. The ALB has security groups that allows traffic from my org's VPN as well bitbucket whitelisted ip's that i found on this site (https://support.atlassian.com/organization-administration/docs/ip-addresses-and-domains-for-atlassian-cloud-products/#AtlassiancloudIPrangesanddomains-OutgoingConnections) and (https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/what-are-the-bitbucket-cloud-ip-addresses-i-should-use-to-configure-my-corporate-firewall/).

I'm able to run the builds from my jenkins instance when i click "build now". However, when i try to trigger the build from a bitbucket push, i get an "ERR_ACCESS_DENIED 0" error.

```
--></style>
</head><body id=ERR_ACCESS_DENIED>
<div id="titles">
<h1>ERROR</h1>
<h2>The requested URL could not be retrieved</h2>
</div>
<hr>

<div id="content">
<p>The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: <a href="https://jenkins-url/*">https://<jenkins-url>/*</a></p>

<blockquote id="error">
<p><b>Access Denied.</b></p>
</blockquote>

<p>Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is incorrect.</p>

<p>Your cache administrator is <a href="mailto:webmaster">webmaster</a>.</p>
<br>
</div>
```

Things i verified:

1. I set up a new app password in bitbucket for my user & then added that user/pass as credentials in jenkins and supplying it in the "bitbucket source" option.
2. I checked the acccess logs in the ALB & i can see the origin IPs and confirmed they are part of the SG & i see the "forward" "=" "200" msg in the log.
3. I added the ingress of bitbucket ips to my EC2 nodes, EKS cluster, ALB SG
4. I took all the headers and body from the "view requests" page & put them in postman and sent a "POST" request, i get back a 200 OK.

Is there anything else that i need to do here . what am i missing, please advise?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you `Jenkins` is running in private subnet and you are accessing it via internal ALB. Also provided links to `Bitbucket` server IP's tells me that you are not hosting your own `Bitbucket` server since those are public IP's and are listed on official doc website.

In that case you will need to provision second load balancer but in public subnet so `Bitbucket` server will be able to reach your `Jenkins` in private subnet.

Example configuration from official `Jenkins` [helm chart](https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts):

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  apiVersion: "networking.k8s.io/v1"
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
  hostName: jenkins.xyz.com
  ingressClassName: internal-nginx
  tls:
    - secretName: tls-wildcard-xyz-com
      hosts:
        - jenkins.xyz.com
  secondaryingress:
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /bitbucket-hook/
  apiVersion: "networking.k8s.io/v1"
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
  hostName: jenkins-webhook.xyz.com
  ingressClassName: external-nginx
  tls:
    - secretName: tls-wildcard-xyz-com
      hosts:
        - jenkins-webhook.xyz.com
```

Please remember that you cannot access resources in private subnet from internet.